# Is there a value that I can use in a SELECT TOP that will return all rows?

Tags: sql-server

I'm allowing the end user to define how many rows are returned by a query (SELECT TOP (@x)). Is there a value that can be entered where all rows are returned? Or do I have to dynamically create the query without the TOP (@x) if they want all rows returned?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Is it `TOP ... ORDER BY` something? Is the `ORDER BY` something still required in the case that you select all?

Comment: I guess uhhh... just omitting the `TOP` is out of the question? Like you're dealing with some predefined query and you have to pass it *something*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it looks like [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a *BIGINT* if you aren't using a *PERCENT*.  That means you could pass in the max value of *BIGINT*,

```
SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) * FROM table1
```

I seriously doubt you will ever see a table that large.  I'm not sure what kind of effect that would have on the query plan though.

Comment: Assuming the variable `@x` is a BIGINT then `SET @x = 0x7fffffffffffffff` may be clearer to some. It's easier to remember anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'll be honest I'm going to look it up either way :)  I've never seen that done before though.  Is that an implicit conversion?

Comment: Well it's easier to remember if you just remember to begin with `7` and then the rest of it is `F` and you need 16 characters in total for the 8 bytes. And yes it will be implicitly converted if assigning to a variable of that datatype.

Comment: @MartinSmith Is it a good practice to rely on binary representation of the value? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) states _The binary representation of a value might change from version to version of SQL Server_. Also, I don't know if I'm the only person, who was always confused by `0x7fffffffffffffff` representation of the max value of `bigint` in SqlServer. The reason is that in SqlServer binary constant notation you have `7f` in the _lowest_ byte, where as in languages like c++ you have it in the _highest_ byte to get max of signed integral type.

Comment: @i-one. The binary representation of integer types is extremely unlikely to change. There would be no point in SQL Server supplying bitwise operators that operate on the integer types if it was not expected we could rely on a specific format.

Comment: And in practice if you look at the code samples for encryption functions they all rely on the binary representation irrespective of what that page says

Answer (score 12):

You could also consider

```
SET ROWCOUNT @x;

SELECT Foo
FROM Bar
ORDER BY Baz;
```

Instead of

```
SELECT TOP (@x) Foo
FROM Bar 
ORDER BY Baz;
```

The value you would need to set @x to is `0` to disable it.

This is deprecated for data modification statements but not deprecated for `SELECT`.

In 2012 a different plan is compiled for the case that `ROWCOUNT` is 0 vs some non zero value.

If the `ORDER BY Baz` is only there to give meaning to the `TOP` rather than to provide a presentation order for results and you don't have an index supporting this then splitting into two queries would avoid an unnecessary sort in the `0` case.

Answer (score 8):

SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT can be used to bypass any errors with using "TOP" in a query.

Comment: To me, that doesn't really explain the reason to use a feature that gets optimised out. Does Crystal Reports *expect* an ORDER BY to be there in the view definition?

Comment: No, Crystal Reports has issues with taking hold of queries and forcing its own execution plans on them, making them very inefficient and sometimes inaccurate.  I prefer to do ALL of my logic and design in the SQL query, and simply make it "pretty" in Crystal.  This is why I have, for the most part, migrated to SSIS/SSRS, but there are still legacy reports out there.

Answer (score -2):

```
select top(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable) * From YourTable
```

Comment: The question is about *parametrising* the TOP clause. The OP already has a parameter (`@x`) there, and they are now asking what value to pass to `@x` so that it would mean "all rows" regardless of how many rows the table actually has. Maybe you could figure out how to adapt your solution to match the OP's requirements.

Comment: I've made the adjustments to fit the question though as written this has a race condition if rows are inserted concurrently. This would require a table lock for the duration to resolve that blocks concurrent inserts. This and the extra expense of checking in the first place can be avoided by just using a large number.

Comment: `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable)` is not a value.